# recursion print error nested dict() object in python

Tags: python, recursion, dictionary, iteration

Let's make it a bit easier.
Code:

```
level3 = {'a':'aa'}                                                             
level2 = {'b':level3, 'd':level3}                                               
level1 = {'j':level2, 'k':level2}                                               

def print_rec(node = None):                                                 
    if node is None:                                                            
        node = level1                                                           
    if node == 'aa':                                                            
        return                                                                  
    for key, successor in node.items():                                         
        print(key,":",node.get(key))                                            
        print_rec(successor)                                                

print_rec()
```

Outputs:

```
k : {'d': {'a': 'aa'}, 'b': {'a': 'aa'}}
d : {'a': 'aa'}
a : aa
b : None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 13, in <module>
    print_rec(level1)
  File "test.py", line 11, in print_rec
    print_rec(node)
  File "test.py", line 11, in print_rec
    print_rec(node)
  File "test.py", line 8, in print_rec
    for key in node:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

**I think node = node.get(key) will be executed only if the key is in node. So why the new node will get a NoneType? Anyone can help?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the for loop, it seems like you're using the name `node` for two different things:

```
for key in node:                                                            
    print(key,":",node.get(key))                                            
    node = node.get(key)                                                    
    print_rec(node)
```

When in the first iteration, you change the value of `node`.  In the second iteration, when you do `node.get(key)`, you're using the new `node`, but you want to be using the original `node`.

This should help:

```
for key in node:
    print(key,":",node.get(key))
    successor = node.get(key)
    print_rec(successor)
```

It can be written even more concisely like this:

```
for key, successor in node.items():
    print(key,":",successor)
    print_rec(successor)
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. Could you show me why "node = node.get(key)" will lead to an unexpected result? If the copy is shallow, can I regard the "node" as a pointer? If so, "node = node.get(key)" will be fine, I think.

Comment: I've added an explanation.

Comment: Thanks. I modified it with a default argument so that when I encapsulate this method in a class, user can call it without accessing private field. I wonder if there more concise way to achieve this?

Comment: And under some situation, if recursion returns with a None, my way may lead to an infinite loop, I think.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. If you want help on this, simply create a new question :)